# Component does not rerender even after setState method in react

Tags: reactjs

I tried to make a todo list that can sorted alphabetically and by time added, but somehow after setState the component does not rerender. Do you have any idea on how it might not work? This is the code (i cut some parts that are not important)

```
  
function App () {
 function sortByAlphabet () {
    setTodoList(currentTodoList => {
      return currentTodoList.sort((a, b) => {
        if(a.title.toUpperCase() < b.title.toUpperCase()) {return -1}
        if(a.title.toUpperCase() > b.title.toUpperCase()) {return 1}
        else return 0
      })
    })

    console.log(todoList)
  }

  function sortByDateAdded () {
    setTodoList(currentTodoList => {
      return currentTodoList.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.date - b.date
      })
    })
    
    console.log(todoList)
  }

return (
    <div className='background'>
      <div className='background2'>
        <Form onSubmit={submit} onChange={onChange} todo={todo}/>
        <DropDown sortBy="Sort By:" sortByAlphabet={sortByAlphabet} sortByDateAdded={sortByDateAdded} />
        <ul>
          {todoList.map(todo => {
            return (
              <div className='todoList'>
                <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => changeCompleted (todo.id)}/>
                <li key={todo.id} className={todo.completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{todo.title}</li>
                <input type="button" value="Delete"onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)} />
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The sort method [_"... returns the reference to the same array, now sorted."_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Elaborating on what @jonrsharpe said, the sort method returns the same array reference so nothing has changed as far as React is concerned and it does not rerender. Replacing `currentTodoList.sort((a, b) => {..});` with `[...currentTodoList].sort((a, b) => {..});` is one way to ensure the array reference is new and React knows to rerender

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
function App() {
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

  // Your other functions......

  function sortByAlphabet() {
    const sortedList = [...todoList].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.title.toUpperCase() < b.title.toUpperCase()) return -1;
      if (a.title.toUpperCase() > b.title.toUpperCase()) return 1;
      return 0;
    });

    setTodoList(sortedList);
  }

  function sortByDateAdded() {
    const sortedList = [...todoList].sort((a, b) => {
      return a.date - b.date;
    });

    setTodoList(sortedList);
  }

  return (
    <div className='background'>
      <div className='background2'>
        <Form onSubmit={submit} onChange={onChange} todo={todo} />
        <DropDown sortBy="Sort By:" sortByAlphabet={sortByAlphabet} sortByDateAdded={sortByDateAdded} />
        <ul>
          {todoList.map(todo => (
            <div className='todoList' key={todo.id}>
              <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => changeCompleted(todo.id)} />
              <li className={todo.completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{todo.title}</li>
              <input type="button" value="Delete" onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```